# Play m3u8 audio streaming in python without saving audio content

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pyqt, m3u8, ffmpeg-python

there is an online radio station and i have a m3u8 url from that like below:

```
http://example.com/live/playlist.m3u8
```

I can capture the audio with ffmpeg with this command:

```
ffmpeg -i "http://example.com/live/playlist.m3u8" -c copy test.aac
```

I want to play this streaming with in my PyQt app and i don't need to store the content.

But i don't know how to pass the content from ffmpeg to my python app and play that with QMediaPlayer.

Comment: QMediaPlayer is intended to play a media resource, not directly reproduce the contents of an video/audio stream. You can use [QMediaPlaylist](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplaylist.html) possibly with `load(QUrl('http://...'))`.

Comment: @musicamante Does it accept m3u8 url?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: @musicamante Yes but i got this error: `DirectShowPlayerService::doRender: Unknown error 0x80040218.`

Comment: Please [edit] your post and provide a [mre] of what you tried

Comment: @AlexMercer The QMediaPlayer backends don't have built-in support for all audio/video formats. If you're on Windows, you will usually need to [install some extra codecs](https://codecguide.com/about_kl.htm).